# image uploading issue

Tags: visualforce, upload, viewstate

How to upload files to an outside service, larger than 3M?
And this error on uploading:  Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded. Actual view state size for this page was 156.719KB

```
<apex:page standardController="Employee__c" extensions="EmployeeUploadPhotoController">
 <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
         <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveEmp}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" showHeader="true">     
            <apex:sectionHeader title="Employee" subtitle="Upload Photo"/>                                   
            <apex:inputFile title="Upload Photo" value="{!body}" fileName="{!name}" accept="png,jpg,bmp,jpeg" id="file"></apex:inputFile>           
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>    
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

controller-

```
public class EmployeeUploadPhotoController{

    public Blob body{get; set;}
    public String name{get; set;}
    public Attachment objAttach{get;set;}
    public Employee__c objEmp{get;set;}

    public EmployeeUploadPhotoController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        objAttach=new Attachment();
        objEmp = (Employee__c)controller.getRecord();
        if(objEmp.id!=null)
            objEmp = [select id from Employee__c where id=:objEmp.id ];
    }

    public pagereference saveEmp(){                
        try {
            upsert objEmp;
            objAttach.body=body;
            objAttach.name=name;
            if(objAttach.body!=null && objAttach.name!=null){       
                objAttach.parentId=objEmp.id;
                upsert objAttach;
                //objEmp.Image_URL__c='https://c.ap1.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+objAttach.id;
                objEmp.Image_URL__c='/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+objAttach.id;
                upsert objEmp;
            }
            objAttach.body=null;
        }        

        catch(Exception e) {            
             return null;
        }

        return new pagereference('/'+objEmp.id);                
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a view state issue. You can post your relevant VF & apex class snippet for better answers.

Comment: can you tell me what changes i should do in controller so that the error will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

You have already cleared out doc.body (objAttach.body=null;) to insure that the blob is not included automatically in the serialized image of the standard controller. So I don't really see any problem anymore. Tested :)

[image: Larger than 3MB image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article.

[An Introduction to Visualforce View State](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce_View_State)

The way to resolve this error is to use the `transient` keyword for the variable that is holding the value of the image

```
public Transient blob body{get;set;}
```